# How to drag a recyclerview item allowing reordering with animations in the RV, OR drag to different recyclerview

Tags: animation, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I am creating an app that allows dragging items either within a recyclerview, or from one RV into another. The goal is that on touch the item can be dragged to either type of location (NOT via a long press for one, short for the other or similar).

I'm using a custom OnDragListener on the RVs themselves and also on the viewHolders in the RV to achieve drag an item from one view to another, which works. I'm using an onTouchListener on a subview of the holder to achieve the drag within the RV, which works, but without any animation as items move into new positions before being released.

I have tried changing return values within both listeners in order to not consume touches, without success.